# How format a list to json2 format?

Tags: r, json

How can I format the following list to json2 subprotocol format?

```
header_entry_new = list(Domain="Login",ID=1, Key=list(Elements=list(ApplicationId=256,AuthenticationToken=123456,
                                                               Position=paste(123445,"/S24533",sep = "")),NameType="AuthnToken"))
```

Comment: you mean this? `jsonlite::toJSON(header_entry_new)`

Comment: Hello, I am not an expert in json format. However, I know that something can be in json5 and etc formats, however, I need json2 (do not know the differences between them)